# What is an easy way to get the ASCII value of a character in Cobol

Tags: cobol

We have to find more than one way to get the ascii value of a character.
On top of that we also need to get the sum of all the characters's ascii values.
I currently have the below and works alright for the first section where you need individual values
.
I just need to know if there is an easier way or a function to do this in Cobol?

```
DATA DIVISION.                                                 
FILE SECTION.                                                  

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                       
01  WS-COUNTERS.                                               
    03  WS-COUNTER                  PIC  9(05).                
    03  WS-INPUT                    PIC  X(01).                
    03  WS-DISPLAY                  PIC  9(03).                

01  W1-ARRAY.                                                  
    03  ALPHABETIC-CHARS OCCURS 26 TIMES PIC X.                

01  W3-ARRAY.                                                  
    03  NUMERIC-CHARS OCCURS 26 TIMES PIC X.                   


PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                            
A000-MAIN SECTION.                                             
BEGIN.                                                         
    PERFORM B000-INITIALIZE.                                   
    PERFORM C000-PROCESS UNTIL WS-COUNTER > 26.                
    PERFORM D000-END.                                          

A099-EXIT.                                                     
    STOP RUN.                                                  

B000-INITIALIZE SECTION.                                       
    ACCEPT WS-INPUT.                                           
    MOVE "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" TO W1-ARRAY.             
    MOVE "01234567890000000000000000" TO W3-ARRAY.             
    MOVE 1 TO WS-COUNTER.                                      
    MOVE 0 TO WS-DISPLAY.                                      

B099-EXIT.                                                     
    EXIT.                                                      

C000-PROCESS SECTION.                                          
C001-BEGIN.                                                    
    IF WS-INPUT IS NUMERIC                                     
       IF NUMERIC-CHARS(WS-COUNTER) = WS-INPUT                 
          COMPUTE WS-DISPLAY = WS-COUNTER + 48 - 1             
       END-IF                                                  
    ELSE                                                       
       IF ALPHABETIC-CHARS(WS-COUNTER) = WS-INPUT              
          COMPUTE WS-DISPLAY = WS-COUNTER + 65 - 1             
       END-IF                                                  
    END-IF.                                                    

    ADD 1 TO WS-COUNTER.                                       


C099-EXIT.                                                     
    EXIT.
```

Comment: Melissa, please consult the documentation for your COBOL. Since the 1985 Standard there has been an intrinsic function which does exactly what you want (irrespective of actual character representation). We're not here to read the manuals for you.

Comment: If you set your execess numbers to characer zeros and add them up 26 times, your answer will not be correct. You have a lot of excess paragraphs and full-stops/periods - are you being taught that?

Comment: Yes I am being taught that. Is there a different standard that you are following? I took out the excess zero's thank you.

Comment: Since the 1985 COBOL Standard (yes, that is 31 years ago) the need of the full-stop/period in the PROCEDURE DIVISION has been greatly reduced. New "scope-terminators" were introduce, like END-IF, END-SEARCH. Unless you are being taugt to use GO TO, you have no need for "exit paragraphs", and no need for SECTION or PERFORM ... THRU .... So you get a lot less clutter and a lot more actual code when you look at a screen/page. And you don't encourage GO TO. Examples here if you wander around in the COBOL tag (for newer questions, anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`FUNCTION ORD`](http://open-cobol.sourceforge.net/faq/index.html#function-ord) and keep in mind that you will get the ordinal number in the program's collating sequence (which may be EBCDIC or not the full ASCII).

As this function was introduced in the COBOL85 standard it should be available in most compilers (your question misses the compiler/machine you use).